# How to play audio input with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, electron

The question is simple. Using NodeJS, how can I play audio that comes from input sources (like microphone or video capture devices)?

I want to make a multiplatform desktop app with Electron, following the idea of USB Camera (an Android app that allows users to see and hear images and audio that comes from external video/audio devices - like EasyCap or WebCams).

So, the starting point I need to learn is how to playback audio from input sources, as well as video sources (but I think is more simple for video, because is like playing webcam image on browser).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is searching something like that, I've found a solution through this link: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/devices/input-output

The concept is to use WebRTC to display image and play sound from any input device (camera, video capture board, etc) on a `<video>` element.

You also can find my project at https://github.com/rbfraphael/video-viewer